# How to take photo from camera on Android and set it into an Image View?

Tags: android, camera, gallery, genymotion

I need to use *camera* in my application. I need to use it to set an image profile. I created an *AlertDialog Builder* to choose if take a pic or choose it from gallery.

When I choose to **Take Photo** I open the camera and I take pic but when I return to my camera I don't see the pic that I take on my **imageView**.

I used the following code:

**on click button**:

```
if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) 
{
 Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
}
```

oh, My **REQUEST_CAMERA** is initialized in that way:

```
private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 1;
```

and on my **onActivityResult** I use thise code:

```
if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
                Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
                File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
                FileOutputStream fo;
                try {
                    destination.createNewFile();
                    fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                    fo.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                etImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            }
}
```

So, I don't know what is the problme... someone can Help me? thanks

Comment: Look for Java stack traces in LogCat.

Comment: @CommonsWare in **locat** I only see that: `E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xeeb2b310`

Comment: Use some breakpoints to make sure that the things you are expecting to be hit in onActivityResult are in fact being hit?

Comment: @zgc7009 I don't use any breakpoint

Comment: Try it, or give some debug logs a shot. Just need to make sure you are actually getting where you expect to in your logic/responses.

Comment: @zgc7009 I try but it works correctly but I don't know why I don't see the image...

Comment: Mind showing us your xml, may be that it is actually loading into the ImageView but the ImageView itself isn't visible, maybe?

Comment: @zgc7009 `<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:background="#DCDCDC"
        android:src="@drawable/nophoto"/>` this is the xml of the imageview